# Insert a node in the front of a Link list using loop

Tags: c++, list, hyperlink, insert

I tried this code.The output of this code is coming 1 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2.
But I want the output 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1.
what's my fault I couldn't understand.I saw this question has previously asked but for my concept clarification I asked this again.Have any better solution of this code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    struct NODE
    {
        int data;
        NODE *next;
    };
    int main()
    {
        int i,j=0;
        NODE *start=NULL,*ptr,*temp;
        for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            ptr = new NODE;
            ptr->data=i;
            if(start==NULL)
            {
                ptr->next=NULL;
                start=ptr;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr->next=start->next;
                start->next=ptr;
            }
        }
        temp=start;
        for ( temp = start; temp; temp = temp->next )
            cout << temp->data << ' ';
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It isn't working

Comment: Just debug it and see why it happens. You wanted to insert a Node at the end? Then change the title

Comment: @FirstStep Thanks.I understand my fault..

Comment: Try adding the link to the other answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop has unnecessary logic. It can simply be:

```
   for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
   {
      ptr = new NODE;
      ptr->data=i;

      // It doesn't matter what start is.
      // The new NODE is added to the front.
      ptr->next=start;

      // Make the new NODE the front(start).
      start=ptr;
   }
```

See it working at http://ideone.com/y62FnG.